# How to delete gateway from default routing table using systemd

Tags: linux, routing, systemd

There are two physical interfaces on my machine, both with DHCP, so my default routing table looks like this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.26.129    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp8s0
default         10.10.24.1      0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eno1
10.10.24.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
10.10.24.1      *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 eno1
```

In order to delete the `10.10.24.1` gateway, I run this:

```
route del default gw 10.10.24.1
```

I want it to be deleted after booting, `systemd` would be the suitable way, but how should I delete gateway from default routing table using `ystemd`?

Below is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
[Unit]
Description=delete gateways from the main routing table

[Service]
Type=idle
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/route -b /etc/iproute2/delgw

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

file **delgw**:

```
del default gw 10.10.24.1
```

Answer (score 2):

In one of your interface's configuration file you have the address 10.10.24.1 set as your default gateway. Just find out which one is it in, remove/comment it out and reboot your server. You won't have to do anything else.

Comment: The address 10.10.24.1 is not likely to be in configuration files as OP uses DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your dhcp configuration file for eno1.

Look for something like

```
interface "eno1" {
send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
supersede domain-name "fugue.com rc.vix.com home.vix.com";
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name;
require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
script "/etc/dhclient-script";
media "media 10baseT/UTP", "media 10base2/BNC";
```

}

Remove "routers" from the line "request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers".

Depending on your distribution, the location of dhclient.conf may change.